# What is fuse Filesystem

Tags: wine, microsoft-office, fuse

While installing the Office 2010 on Linux Ubuntu I received the error message that

```
Error: The following file is located on a Fuse Filesystem. It may prevent wine from working.
```

I'm using PlayonLinux to install Office 2010

Any Suggestions.

Ok disabled the Security Check as told by @Rinzwind

Wine said that

Error: Wine seems to have crashed. If your program is running, Just ignore this message

So I ignored it and moved on by clicking NEXT, but then it displayed the Error message

> Error: Binary not found: WINWORD.EXE, EXCEL.EXE OUTLOOK.EXE. Have
>   you installed the program to the default Location?

Why is saying that when I didn't installed it.

I'm using. Iso image of office as source

Answer (score 4):

- You are installing your software on a NTFS partition and that system is mounted using a [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) driver.
- You can disable this test by opening the PlayOnLinux console and typing:

  ```
  POL_Config_Write NO_FSCHECK TRUE
  ```

  But you will get no support if you use this since Wine does not guarantee correct execution of programs on anything but [POSIX filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) so it throws an error.

[Source 1](http://www.playonmac.com/en/issue-1622.html) and [source 2](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-8816-PlayOnLinux_refuses_to_start_games_stored_on_NTFS.html)

> Regarding the edit

You need to take a close look at the installation script. If you trying to install the 64bit version or the professional version of Office 2010 only the 32bit normal version is supported.

Comment: i have updated the question and added the information based on latest tests. Please check underbold text