# Request for instruction for installing the clubdeck install in Ubuntu

Tags: wine

I have tried the clubhouse in different android simulation in windows and Ubuntu, but it was successful with [clubdeck](https://www.clubdeck.app/) (based on my tries on win and Ubuntu like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359708/problem-in-installing-the-clubhouse-via-apt-command) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369862/how-to-install-clubhouse-in-an-android-emulator-on-ubuntu)), so if possible I like to have some instruction or tested way for installing the [clubdeck](https://www.clubdeck.app/) in Ubuntu, as you can see below:

[image]

I guess it could be done by WINE or other windows simulation but asked here for having some index for other clubhouse users and better achievement like fast and easier test and …

My OS info is :

```
$ sudo cat /etc/lsb-release 
[sudo] password for so-pc: 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
```

**Update 1 :**

I understand some tips for the clubdeck and that is you must firstly register the number of your phone with in android phone then use the clubdeck otherwise the clubdeck don't work.

**Update 2:**

I have installed the wine and tried to install the clubdeck but get the below errors:

```
 sudo wine Clubdeck.Setup.1.7.0.exe
[sudo] password for so-pc: 
wine: created the configuration directory '/root/.wine'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in L"/root/.wine" has been updated.
0045:err:ole:create_server class {9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39} not registered
0045:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39} could be created for context 0x4
so-pc@sopc-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:/media/so-pc/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa2next/Softwares/Others$ 0047:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1089:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:641:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
```

**Update 3:**

I have tried the playonlinux and get the below error:

[image]

And the playonlinux codes and ... could be seen below:

```
Others$ playonlinux
Looking for python... 
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.18 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk3
selected
1
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.3.4) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[POL_Config_Write] Message: Config write: VDRIVES_LINK_MADE TRUE
[Check_OpenGL] Warning: check_dd_x86 missing, test skipped
[Check_OpenGL] Warning: check_dd_amd64 missing, test skipped
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/so-pc/.PlayOnLinux/
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: ScreenCap...
[install_plugins] Message:    -->Installing plugin: 'ScreenCap'.
[install_plugins] Message: Checking plugin: PlayOnLinux Vault...
[install_plugins] Message:    -->Installing plugin: 'PlayOnLinux Vault'.
[update_check] Message: Web version : 1635286417
[update_check] Message: Current local version : 
[update_check] Message: Updating list
[POL_SetupWindow_Init] Message: Creating new window for pid 65625
[POL_SetupWindow_Close] Message: Closing window for pid 65625
[POL_Config_Write] Message: Config write: MANUAL_INSTALL_INCREMENT 1
[POL_SetupWindow_Init] Message: Creating new window for pid 65625
[POL_SetupWindow_menu] Message: menu answer: Install a program in a new virtual drive
[POL_SetupWindow_textbox] Message: textbox answer: clubdeck
[POL_Wine_SelectPrefix] Message: Selecting prefix: clubdeck
[POL_SetupWindow_checkbox_list] Message: checkbox_list answer: Use another version of Wine
find: ‘/home/so-pc/.PlayOnLinux//wine/linux-x86/*’: No such file or directory
[POL_SetupWindow_menu] Message: menu answer: System
[POL_System_SetArch] Message: POL_ARCH set to x86
[POL_SetupWindow_menu_num] Message: menu_num answer: 1
[POL_System_SetArch] Message: POL_ARCH set to amd64
[POL_Wine_PrefixCreate] Message: No version specified. Using system version (wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1))
[POL_Wine_PrefixCreate] Message: Creating prefix ()...
[POL_Wine_PrefixCreate] Message: Setting WINEARCH to win64
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/so-pc/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/clubdeck'
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0012:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0012:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0012:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0012:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {00000131-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
0014:err:ole:marshal_object couldn't get IPSFactory buffer for interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}
0014:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hres=0x80004002
0014:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, 80004002
0014:err:ole:get_local_server_stream Failed: 80004002
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
Could not find Wine Gecko. HTML rendering will be disabled.
wine: configuration in L"/home/so-pc/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/clubdeck" has been updated.
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine- --version (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
[POL_Wine] Message: Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
[POL_Config_PrefixWrite] Message: Prefix config write: ARCH amd64
[POL_Config_Write] Message: Config write: WINE_SYSTEM_ARCH amd64
/usr/bin/wineserver
[POL_LoadVar_PROGRAMFILES] Message: Getting Program Files name
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine- cmd /c echo %ProgramFiles% (Working directory : /usr/share/playonlinux/python)
[POL_Wine] Message: Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 0
[main] Message: Autorun : Checking ACAC8B5FAC8B2346...
[main] Message: Autorun: Found 0 media
[POL_SetupWindow_browse] Message: browser answer: /media/so-pc/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa2next/Softwares/Others/Clubdeck.Setup.1.7.0.exe
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /media/so-pc/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa2next/Softwares/Others/Clubdeck.Setup.1.7.0.exe
[FS_Check] Error: The following file is located on a fuse filesystem.
It might prevent wine from working

/media/so-pc/ACAC8B5FAC8B2346/Elasa2next/Softwares/Others/Clubdeck.Setup.1.7.0.exe
[POL_Config_Write] Message: Config write: LAST_TIMESTAMP 1635286417
```

Bus as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245272/what-is-fuse-filesystem) post I guess it needs to install some other libraries for playonlinux like some things from the below list, which I was unable to install them!:
[image]

**update 4:**

based of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999294/how-to-run-exe-file-in-ubuntu) post, I have tried to install it by mono, but I get below error:

```
sudo mono Clubdeck.Setup.1.7.0.exe
Cannot open assembly 'Clubdeck.Setup.1.7.0.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

**Update 5:**

I have tried some procedure for debugging the installation clubdeck in plauyonlinux like installing the **winehq** from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984844/e-unable-to-locate-package-winehq-stable), and finally it has been installed but by running it I get below error (playonlinux logs are available [here](https://rentry.co/3dsg4)):

[image]

**Update 6:**

I have tried the virtual desktop of the wine as you can see from the below photo:

[image]

And copied the EXE file of clubdeck in the wine system folder and tried to install the clubdec EXE file aging, and it worked as you can see below, but I don't know for the first install by the normal installation on the palyonlinux the clubdeck don't worked!?
[image]
Thanks.

Comment: @guiverc, excuse me, I don't get what is your means.

Comment: @guiverc,  I have added it on the question, it is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @guiverc,Ya, it is desktop, but I ordinarily add these details based on the Ubuntu release info command and I guess these are ok, because there are much information which are missing, and I don't know what are important until the others requesting for them.